# Build the list {1,2,3} with the minimum assignment statements in C

Tags: c, linked-list

Rewrite this to minimize the assignment statements

```
/*
 Build the list {1, 2, 3} in the heap and store
 its head pointer in a local stack variable.
 Returns the head pointer to the caller.
*/
struct node* BuildOneTwoThree() {
struct node* head = NULL;
struct node* second = NULL;
struct node* third = NULL;
head = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); // allocate 3 nodes in the hea
second = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
third = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
head->data = 1; // setup first node
head->next = second; // note: pointer assignment rule
second->data = 2; // setup second node
second->next = third;
third->data = 3; // setup third link
third->next = NULL;
// At this point, the linked list referenced by "head"
// matches the list in the drawing.
return head;
}
```

From http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/

Comment: Can anybody say, "Give me teh codez"? You need to add more detail about what you've tried, what isn't working, etc. Nobody here wants to strictly write your code for you. (Also, if this is homework then tag it as such).

Comment: @Justin : Then don't write the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
node *head;
node **next= &head;

int next_value= 1;
while (next_value<=3)
{
    *next= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    (*next)->data= next_value;
    next= &(*next)->next;
    ++next_value;
}

*next= 0;
```

Comment: Nice.  Don't know why I did not realise this had to be homework, though.

Comment: @Steve. I know you could do it. It's Sad that you thought it was a homework questions,though.

Comment: @kunjaan - the 'homework' tag on a question tends to make me think it is homework...

Comment: What is `&(*next)` for?

Comment: @user2030677, `&(*next)->next` gets the address of the pointer to update. It's equivalent to `&((*next)->next)`.

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing:

```
node* buildNodeList(unsigned int n)
{
    node * head;
    node * prev;
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    prev = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        head->data = n;
        head->next = prev;
        prev = head;
        --n;
    }

    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two assignments; complete compilable code follows :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};

struct node *newnode(int val, int nextval) {
  struct node *x = malloc(sizeof *x);  /* not assignment: initialization */
  if (x == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "oops, no memory\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  x->data = val;                                           /* assignments: 1 */
  x->next = (nextval < 4)                                  /* assignments: 2 */
          ? (newnode(nextval, nextval+1))
          : (NULL);
  return x;
}

int main(void) {
  struct node *head = newnode(1, 2); /* not assignment: initialization */
  struct node *curr;

  /* building of the list (3 elements with `data` values from 1 to 3) done */
  /* the assignments after this line are not used to BUILD the list */

  /* use nodes */
  curr = head;
  while (curr) {
    printf(" %d ==>", curr->data);
    curr = curr->next;
  }

  /* free structures */
  curr = head;
  while (curr) {
    struct node *tmp = curr->next;
    free(curr);
    curr = tmp;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More general:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

node *BuildList(int len, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    node *head, **p = &head;
    va_start(args, len);
    while(len--) {
        *p = malloc(sizeof(node));
        (*p)->data = va_arg(args, int);
        p = &(*p)->next;
    }
    *p = 0;
    va_end(args);
    return head;
}
```